# CSS Position: absolute and Z-index can't get text Div to overlap images echoed from Database?

Tags: php, html, css

From phpmyadmin database I'm trying to echo out my `username` and `img_name` rows from my `images` table. The problem I'm getting is this:

[Image snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsYEj.png)

The divs with string "name" (from `$row['username']`) are not overlapping the checkmark images (from `$row['img_name']`), but are sitting to the right side of the images. The checkmark images called `#indeximg` have a `position: relative` instead of `absolute` because if I set it to `absolute` the images will sit atop of  each other which is not what I want. I want the "name" divs called `span#names` to sit atop of each of its corresponding `#indeximg`s. Is there something I'm missing in my CSS code?

This is my entire code here:

```html
<style>
div.topicscats {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 360px;
}
#indeximg {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    z-index: 2;
}
span#names {
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    z-index: 3;
}
</style>

<div class="topicscats"> 
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "photos";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$membsql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $membsql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {     

  echo "<img style='' id='indeximg' src='images/".$row['img_name']."'>
        <div class='names'><span id='names'>".$row['username']."</span></div>";
}  

?>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Please post the rendered HTML in your question.

Comment: @j08691 I added the php, sql, and database tags because my code included them and it could have something to do with them.

Comment: It doesn't; they don't. The only things that're relevant to your question, at least initially, are the (rendered) HTML and CSS.

Comment: give your names a relative and add a left px to your image, add top ps until you receive what you want

Comment: @dean But giving giving images a left value leaves a huge margin gap on its left side, and giving the names a relative results in the images and names appearing like stairs instead of a horizontal line?

Comment: @j08691 But would you be able to assist me with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a wrapper div which is `relative`, and then you can `absolute` position the image and the name to the top-left corner of this wrapper.

```html
<style>
div.topicscats {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 360px;
}
div.wrap{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    z-index: 2;
}
#indeximg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
span#names {
    position: absolute;
    color: blue;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="topicscats"> 
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "photos";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$membsql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $membsql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {     

  echo "<div class="wrap"><img style='' id='indeximg' src='images/".$row['img_name']."'>
        <div class='names'><span id='names'>".$row['username']."</span></div></div>";
}  

?>
</div>
```